# How can I execute PhoneGaps device properties and Body onLoad another function?

Tags: javascript, cordova

So I cant really get this to work out for some reason...
I'm trying to have (PhoneGap/Cordova) to load device properties like so:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
        'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' +
        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }
</script>

<p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
```

Which loads completely fine, though what I cannot accomplish is trying to use:

```
<script>
function begin()
{
    document.getElementById('web').innerHTML = '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example.com/page.php?uuid=' + device.uuid + '">';
}
</script>

<div id="web"></div>

<body onload="begin()">
```

It's supposed to load a meta refresh along with the "device uuid" property, although, it doesnt load the page at or anything...

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why it's not working, is because, the page is attempting to wait for "device ready"  from cordova.js. Once it finishes loading it loads the device properties. Which overruled the body onload to execute the meta refresh. To solve this we can combine the two functions into one, so that when device=ready. Cordova.js will load the meta refresh as-well.

Instead of having it two separate 'functions' combine them like so:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
        'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' +
        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';

        document.getElementById('logg').innerHTML = '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example.com/page.php?uuid=' + device.uuid + '">';
}
</script>

<div id="logg"></div>

<!--- above = METARefresh --->
<!---bellow= properties --->

<p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
```

Keep in mind, that unless you edit it; The user will see the device properties until "example.com" loads.

If you dont want them to see the device properties (Which is suggested); remove this:

```
 <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
```